# Softlayer API : How to get list of active usage prices of object storage?

Tags: java, api, storage, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

How can I get all active usage prices in control UI?
Using the api below, I only get the prices of object storage.
To get the prices of object storage bandwidth and cdn bandwidth, what should I do more?

```
Service service = Package.service(client, 206);
service.withMask().categories();
service.withMask().categories().groups().prices().item().activeUsagePrices();
service.getObject();
```

[Softlayer UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhgHX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getObjectStorageDatacenters

here a rest example:

```
URL: https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/206/getObjectStorageDatacenters

Method: Get
```

Regards

Comment: control.softlayer.com is using the package 206 and it gives right prices except some information missed. I think the package 0 is something old and not used now. By the way, prices should not be hard-coded because they change as time goes. Please let me have the best solution to implement this.

Comment: using the package 0 you will see the cdn bandwidt and the object storage price, the another one maybe is in another package

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you ! :-D